# JavaScript - recursive function (plugin?) with changing arguments until number is reached (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm looking to improve a script I've written in jQuery to do some animation that chains multiple animations together (in somewhat of a timeline sequence). Instead of manually chaining each individual animation, I'd like to write a function to replace a few elements that are standard in each animation.

Admittedly, I don't have the JavaScript knowledge to know the best practices to accomplish this; that being said, some pointers/examples would be fantastic.

Here's what I've got:

```
function itemsFirstAnim() {

    // Define each target div
    var one = $(".one");
    var two = $(".two");
    var three = $(".three");
    var four = $(".four");
    var five = $(".five");
    var six = $(".six");
    var seven = $(".seven");
    var eight = $(".eight");
    var nine = $(".nine");
    var ten = $(".ten");
    var eleven = $(".eleven");
    var twelve = $(".twelve");

    // Show a block (opacity 1), give the overlay a position, show and animate it
    twelve.css("opacity", 1).children(".overlay").show().animate({ right: "100%" }, 750, function() {
        // cover the block with the overlay when the animation is done
        twelve.children('.overlay').css({ right: 0 });

        eleven.css("opacity", 1).children(".overlay").show().animate({ bottom: "100%" }, 750, function() {      
            eleven.children('.overlay').css({ bottom: 0 });

            seven.css("opacity", 1).children(".overlay").show().animate({ right: "100%" }, 750, function() {
                seven.children(".overlay").css({ right: 0 });

                and so on....
        });         
        });

    });
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have arguments of `target` and `direction` to replace the initial selector (i.e. `twelve`) and it's animation direction (i.e. `right: "100%"`). Since each `target` and `direction` is different, I can't just write a function and call it inside of itself, unless I nested it 12 times, which also seems rudimentary at best.

Finally, I'd like this function (or maybe a plugin?) to stop executing when all 12 of these have been applied.

Unfortunately, the order of the animation is not sequential (as show in the example. I do know the order of the numbers to animate, however).

Here's an example of what I've got: http://codepen.io/anon/full/Dxzpj

If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a working example online? It's not too clear what your code does at present...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not particularly beautiful, but you can customize the order of animations however you want by using custom queues; see the [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) functions.

A simple example might look like:

```
$(function () {
  // Use the body to track the animation queue; you can use whatever
  // element you want, though, since we're using a custom queue name
  var $body = $(document.body);

  // Helper functions to cut down on the noise
  var continue_queue = function () {
    $body.dequeue("my-fx");
  };
  var add_to_queue = function (cb) {
    $body.queue("my-fx", cb);
  };

  // Define your queue.  Be sure to use continue_queue as the callback
  add_to_queue(function () {
    $('#one').animate({ height: '8em' }, 750, continue_queue);
  });
  add_to_queue(function () {
    $('#two').animate({ width: '8em' }, 750, continue_queue);
  });

  // Need to call this once to start the sequence
  continue_queue();
});
```

This will track the progress of your overall animation using a separate queue attached to the `<body>` element.  When each part of the animation finishes, it calls `continue_queue()` to indicate that the next part should run.

You can use this approach to build your animation piecemeal—in separate functions, a loop, etc.  And it won't actually start running until you fire it off.

You can see this live and mess with it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqFtF/1/).

Comment: afterthought: you can also use promises to chain animations together independently, though it's noisy in its own way too: `$.when($one.animate(...)).then($two.animate(...))...`

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying the same settings to all of your elements, a simple recursion could help a lot.

```
  var $els = $('#one, #two, #three'); // collect all your elements in an array

  (function recursive(el) {
    el.animate({height: '100px'}, 800, function() {
          if (el.next()) recursive(el.next()); // if there are more, run the function again
    });
  })($els.eq(0)); //start with the first one
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uyGGk/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm animating different properties (top, right, bottom , left). Also, they aren't in sequential order, so `.next()` won't work properly.